# sudo apt install ruby not working

Tags: apt, ruby

When running
`sudo apt install ruby`
or
`sudo apt install ruby-full`

And checking `ruby -v` I get the error:

```
user@C-Ubuntu:~$ ruby -v

Command 'ruby' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install ruby  # version 2.7.0, or
sudo apt  install ruby

See 'snap info ruby' for additional versions.
```

Even when running `sudo apt purge ruby ruby-full` or `sudo apt remove ruby ruby-full`

Help is greatly appriciated :)

Comment: What do you get when you run `sudo apt install ruby`?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu are you using?
I've tested it in my **Ubuntu 18.04** and able to install with below command.

```
$ sudo apt install ruby
```

try to do the following and see if it helps.

```
$ sudo snap install ruby –classic
```

Check this link below, which has alternate methods of installation in case of "apt & snap" are not working.

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-ruby-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 0):

Seems that only the snap install works. But still on ubuntu 18.04 apt install does not work.
(Tested on 2 different Ubuntu 18 systems)